# Android Native Build Issue error while building apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Hello I Imorted a Github source code of Telegram. But when I am trying to build the apk then I got thwo type of error- 
First is - **External Native Build Issues** which contain below details-

```
Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\Users\The\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\The\Desktop\ProjectXYZ\Appcode1\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\The\Desktop\ProjectXYZ\Appcode1\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/The/Desktop/ProjectXYZ/Appcode1/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7_SDK23/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\The\Desktop\ProjectXYZ\Appcode1\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7_SDK23\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

Android NDK: ERROR:C:\Users\The\Desktop\ProjectXYZ\Appcode1\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    

Android NDK: Check that C:/Users/The/Desktop/ProjectXYZ/Appcode1/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_armeabi-v7a.a exists  or that its path is correct   

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
```

Second error pointed to toward file- **C:\Users\The\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\prebuilt-library.mk** which contains this -

```
Error:(44, 0) *** Android NDK: Aborting. Stop.
Open File
```

**Code of prebuilt-library.mk file**- https://gist.github.com/AmitSinghLive/39ecc66092cc23aa9d30abef3b013dfa

I am using latest android studio and source can be found from here- https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

Comment: anyone know how to solve this error ?

Comment: I had the same problem. It was a problem of path length limit. Try putting the source code in C hard drive root or shorten the source code path.

Comment: have anyone solved this error?

Answer (score 0):

1.Shorten your file path.
2.Build -> Refresh Linked C++ Projects